# why isn't dynamically changing css style.left and style.top working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move an image when the keys w, a, s, and d are pressed, but nothing is happening, and nothing is showing up in the console. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var moveBy = 10;
function moveObj(name, xPix, yPix)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(name);
    var xp = parseInt(obj.style.left) + xPix;
    var yp = parseInt(obj.style.top) + yPix;
    obj.style.left = xp;
    obj.style.top = yp;
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').keydown(function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 68)
        {
            moveObj('player', moveBy, 0);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 65)
        {
            moveObj('player', -moveBy, 0);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 87)
        {
            moveObj('player', 0, -moveBy);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 83)
        {
            moveObj('player', 0, moveBy);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you set a position? You can't move an element (with top and left) without setting position to relative, absolute etc.

Comment: put this in `moveObj` to see if it's actually being called: `console.log(arguments);`. Set the new value with the units, i.e. `obj.style.left = xp + 'px';`. Also make sure the element you're changing the position of has a `position` property, you're probably looking for `position: absolute;`. Adding the `HTML` to your post would help.

Comment: ^^ good point, native javascript needs units, the question is why aren't you using jQuery

Comment: Also, if you're using a variable `xp` with units of `px`, make very sure you've not mis-typed one/both...

Comment: @Greggg if you added your comment as an answer I would accept it

Comment: This is how it should be done me thinks -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LJAVS/2/**

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `position: relative` on your player object?

That will be needed to move the player. If you have it set to `static`, it'll not move.

Comment: For extra info, it'll also be `static` if no `position` was defined, as it is the default value.

Answer (score 1):

put this in `moveObj` to see if it's actually being called: `console.log(arguments);`. Set the new value with the units, i.e. `obj.style.left = xp + 'px';`. Also make sure the element you're changing the position of has a `position` property, you're probably looking for `position: absolute;`. Adding the HTML to your post would help.